# ListView gets not scrollable

Tags: xaml, listview, layout, uwp, scrollbar

I have a proble which seems pretty common and has been asked alot, but I can't find a fixing solution for my problem.

So **I try to use 3 listviews in in one page** all shall have a title and an explaining image, **but instead of designing all 3** ListViews **in one page I outsourced one listview with image and title into a control**, which I use in my page.

The 3 Controls are placed in a grid. **When the listview items get filled thy scrollbar should become visible** if the remaining space is no longer enough but it won't show.

**I provided a sandbox project** where I placed the control and etc. like in the application I'm working on. [SampleProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgo9rle1pkrqg2j/ScrollViewSandBox.zip?dl=0)

Their you just need to press start and the listviews get filled. But they don't show the scrollbar.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1: 
As requested I share my code below. If you open up the sample project then you do not need to read further until a second edit is done.**

Control containing listview:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Section"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="grdTitleArea"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Height="50">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <BitmapIcon 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Tapped="grdTitleArea_Tapped"
                UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/area.png"
                Height="40" />
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Tapped="grdTitleArea_Tapped"
                Text="Area"
                Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>

        <!--<ScrollViewer 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
            >-->
            <ListView x:Name="ListView" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Margin="1"
                        Height="50">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionDescription}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Control which contains the control above 3 times:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ProgressControl">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:SynchronizeSettingsControl
                Visibility="Visible"
                x:Name="Settings" />
            <local:SynchronizeSectionControl
                x:Name="ActualAction"
                Visibility="Visible"
                Grid.Row="1" />
            <local:SynchronizeSectionControl
                x:Name="Error"
                Visibility="Visible"
                Grid.Row="2" />
            <local:SynchronizeSectionControl
                x:Name="Log"
                Visibility="Visible"
                Grid.Row="3" />
        </Grid>
```

Page which contains the control which contains the listview:

```xml
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                Text="Demo" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="70" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Content="Useless Button" />
        </Grid>
        <Controls:SynchronizeControl
            x:Name="ctlSync"
            Grid.Row="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            x:Name="btnStart" 
            Content="Start" 
            Tapped="btnStart_Tapped"
            Grid.Row="3" />            
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, links can break after some time, making questions much harder to follow.

Comment: @kennyzx done ✓

Comment: Can't try at the moment but will have a go when I'm home later. But try not to use the `auto` property on your RowDefinitions.  It tends to screw with a lot of the UI stuff. At least that's what I experienced.

Comment: @Daniel this really worked! But I don't get it... I thought the scrollviewer get activated when the child element or something simmilar hits the bounderies of its parent...

Comment: Please write this as an answer and I will accept it! Also I will provide an updated question where I will tell the people what not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you used the `Auto` property for the height of your rows in your control.

This works fine is the control you use uses a definite space. Like a button or similar stuff. But when the control can extend indefinitely the allocation for the space gets screwed up.

Basically the control displays at its maximum size but extends way over its boundaries.

You can prevent that when you use the `*` as a Height value. 
This will lead to the control taking up all the space available. You can further limit this with using the `MaxHeight` property.

If you do it that way it will display a scrollviewer when necessary and it will even resize when you change the window size.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you used `Auto` height in the page. This means basically that the page tells the `local:SynchronizeSectionControl` control: "You can use whichever height you want".

The control then has `*` as the height of the second row which means "use the rest space available". But because the page offered essentially "infinite height", the `ListView` height will stretch as much as possible to accommodate for all its items and hence it doesn't scroll, as its height is big enough to display everything, although it is cut off and not visible, because the window height is of course limited.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I think this will help other people alot.